# How to use SUBSTRING() inside of a SQL Component in Matillion Flow?

Tags: sql, substring, matillion

I am trying to use `SUBSTRING()` to a `filename` environment variable in the SQL Component in Matillion. Is there a different syntax, or is it not allowed in Matillion?

I need to update values in a column with `year` which I can get using `SUBSTRING()` on the file name variable.

This is what I am including in the SQL Component:
`${$year}` being the filename variable

```
UPDATE "tablename"
SET DATAYEAR = SUBSTRING(${$year},5,4)
```

Am I missing something?
Or if someone can suggest a better way of doing it! Thanks!

Comment: What SQL is Matillion generating? You can view it by clicking on the component and then the SQL tab.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a SQL Script component inside of an Matillion Orchestration, or a SQL component inside of a Matillion Transformation?

Orchestration:
If your environment variable name is 'filename', you should be able to accomplish this with:

```
UPDATE "tablename"
SET DATAYEAR = SUBSTRING(${filename},5,4)
```

Transformation:
You would use a Calculator component and overwrite the value of DATAYEAR with the same logic 'SUBSTRING(${filename},5,4)' or perform the same in a SQL component, but in the form of a 'Select'. Then, you'd attach the Calculator or SQL component to a 'Write' component, to update the target table.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out my error right after I posted here haha. Thank you tho!